# how to set a primefaces theme in portlet project

Tags: primefaces, liferay, portlet

I'm developing a portlet project with primefaces and I want to change the default theme.
I made a custom theme with jquery themeRoller and I made a jar file containing the theme as explained in the official documentation.

The problem is the css resource is not found :

```
Unable to find or serve resource, myTheme.css, from library, primefaces-myTheme.
```

NB: in web.xml I put:

```
   <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>myTheme</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Help please

Answer (score 0):

Have you put your jar file in the 'lib' folder? Have you followed the theme directory structure properly? Check out this link.

> http://chawi3.com/2012/05/18/add-custom-theme-primefaces/